# Retaining reference to properties in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, properties, automatic-ref-counting

I have a custom object property in my class. I allocate this object in a function. Once the function is done executing the property is deallocated. I do not want that to happen. I want the object to remain until the reference to `MyClass` is active.
This is with ARC.

This is the code

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) MyCustomClass *obj;
@end

@implementation MyClass

- (id)init {
// initialize 
_obj = nil;
}

- (void)func {
 _obj = [[MyCustomClass alloc] initWithParams...];
// do more things 
}

// the object deallocates once the function exits.
```

Comment: You say "this is with ARC", but I would have to deny that. With ARC, assigning to `_obj` also retains, and the MyCustomClass object will not be released unless you replace it, or unless the MyClass itself is deallocated. I suggest you implement `dealloc` and see whether that's the case. Either it is, or you are not running under ARC as you believe.

Comment: By the way there is no reason to say `_obj = nil` in the initializer. It is already `nil`.

Comment: In the only provided code `_obj` would store new instance of `MyCustomClass` independently with or w/o ARC. If it is deallocated on function exit it means ARC is on (otherwise it would either leak or persist), and!, something in *do more things* either replaces `_obj` instance or set it to `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

There is something else going on elsewhere in your code, as the code provided above will not deallocate that `MyCustomClass` instance. A few possible things that might cause the instance referenced by `_obj` to be released include:

- `_obj` is getting set to `nil` somewhere else;
- `_obj` is getting set again (e.g. you called `func` again) and the old instance will be released; or
- `MyClass`, the parent object, is, itself, getting deallocated.

I’d suggest two things to diagnose what’s going on:

1. First, I would advise adding `dealloc` methods to both `MyClass` and `MyCustomClass` so you can see when they’re deallocated:

   ```
   - (void)dealloc {
       NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
   }
   ```
2. If you still can’t deduce what’s going on, I’d suggest using Instruments to track every reference to the object in question.

   So, for example, fire up up the profiler (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> or “Product” » “Profile”) and choose the “Leaks” instrument. Before you start recording a session, make sure the “Recording Options...” for the “Allocations” instrument *is not* set to “Discard events for freed memory”, but *is* set to “Record reference counts”:

   [image]

   You can now record your profiling session. Personally, I added the “Points of Interest” tool and added a signpost where I created that `MyClass` instance,

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       os_log_t log = os_log_create("ViewController", OS_LOG_CATEGORY_POINTS_OF_INTEREST);
       os_signpost_id_t identifier = os_signpost_id_generate(log);

       os_signpost_event_emit(log, identifier, "MyClass");

       MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];  // the problem here is that I’m using a local variable for the parent class, but the situation in your case may vary
       [myClass func];
   }
   ```

   But if you know when this object is being created, you might not need to do that. But it’s nice to see these signposts in Instruments.

   Anyway, exercise your app so that you can manifest the problem. Then stop the recording. Then choose the Allocations tool and find your object:

   [image]

   You can (by clicking on the arrow next to your address for that object) can then see every reference added and removed:

   [image]

Not only do I see that it was freed, but I can see the full stack trace where this took place. Note, the `func` method is not in this stack trace, but rather I was in `viewDidLoad`, inside the `dealloc` of `MyClass`, which triggered the `dealloc` of `MyCustomClass`. I can even double click on the `viewDidMethod` in my stack on the right and be taken directly where it took place:

[image]

I can now see the problem, that I “accidentally” made `MyClass` a local variable. So I’d change it to use that property (which is currently commented out), and the problem will go away.

Now the precise source of the problem in your case will undoubtedly vary, but through judicious `dealloc` logging and with Instruments’ ability to show us every reference that has been added and removed, you should be able to diagnose the problem. And don’t forget to go up the full stack trace (focusing on your code in white) and see if everything there makes sense. Often we will dwell on the property in question (the `obj` in your example) and forget to look at what’s going earlier in the stack trace.